# Does anyone know how to create more releases of mongodb using digital ocean clusters?

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, digital-ocean, persistent-volumes

I'm trying digital ocean clusters I have 2 nodes 160gb available disk, 8vcpus and 16GB of memory, my cluster is empty and when I a ran

```
helm upgrade --install mongodb1 bitnami/mongodb --set auth.rootPassword=secretpassword --set auth.username=mongodb --set auth.password=mongodb --set auth.database=my_database --set persistence.size=1Gi
```

```
helm upgrade --install mongodb2 bitnami/mongodb --set auth.rootPassword=secretpassword --set auth.username=mongodb --set auth.password=mongodb --set auth.database=my_database --set persistence.size=1Gi
```

.....

```
helm upgrade --install mongodb4 bitnami/mongodb --set auth.rootPassword=secretpassword --set auth.username=mongodb --set auth.password=mongodb --set auth.database=my_database --set persistence.size=1Gi
```

mongodb4 release fails, I get this error

```
Events:
  Type     Reason             Age                    From                Message
  ----     ------             ----                   ----                -------
Events:
  Type     Reason             Age                   From                Message
  ----     ------             ----                  ----                -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling   33m                   default-scheduler   0/2 nodes are available: 2 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims. preemption: 0/2 nodes are available: 2 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling.
  Warning  FailedScheduling   18m (x2 over 28m)     default-scheduler   0/2 nodes are available: 2 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims. preemption: 0/2 nodes are available: 2 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling.
  Normal   NotTriggerScaleUp  2m58s (x31 over 33m)  cluster-autoscaler  pod didn't trigger scale-up:
```

Not sure why this happens,has anyone had this problem before?

Resumen: 3 mongodb release are ok, the 4th always fails.

```
kubectl get pv,pvc,sc -A

NAME                                                        CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM              STORAGECLASS       REASON   AGE
persistentvolume/pvc-633ca5df-7585-4351-aaba-a0890047f471   1Gi        RWO            Delete           Bound    default/mongodb3   do-block-storage            2m27s
persistentvolume/pvc-7006cea5-a3af-45e8-8c9a-10236e4d5816   1Gi        RWO            Delete           Bound    default/mongodb2   do-block-storage            2m36s
persistentvolume/pvc-94d43f36-e882-4239-a2c9-b60bcb53b1ad   1Gi        RWO            Delete           Bound    default/mongodb1   do-block-storage            2m44s

NAMESPACE   NAME                             STATUS    VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS       AGE
default     persistentvolumeclaim/mongodb1   Bound     pvc-94d43f36-e882-4239-a2c9-b60bcb53b1ad   1Gi        RWO            do-block-storage   2m46s
default     persistentvolumeclaim/mongodb2   Bound     pvc-7006cea5-a3af-45e8-8c9a-10236e4d5816   1Gi        RWO            do-block-storage   2m37s
default     persistentvolumeclaim/mongodb3   Bound     pvc-633ca5df-7585-4351-aaba-a0890047f471   1Gi        RWO            do-block-storage   2m28s
default     persistentvolumeclaim/mongodb4   Pending                                                                        do-block-storage   2m15s

NAMESPACE   NAME                                                      PROVISIONER                 RECLAIMPOLICY   VOLUMEBINDINGMODE   ALLOWVOLUMEEXPANSION   AGE
            storageclass.storage.k8s.io/do-block-storage (default)    dobs.csi.digitalocean.com   Delete          Immediate           true                   42h
            storageclass.storage.k8s.io/do-block-storage-retain       dobs.csi.digitalocean.com   Retain          Immediate           true                   42h
            storageclass.storage.k8s.io/do-block-storage-xfs          dobs.csi.digitalocean.com   Delete          Immediate           true                   42h
            storageclass.storage.k8s.io/do-block-storage-xfs-retain   dobs.csi.digitalocean.com   Retain          Immediate           true                   42h
```

```
kubectl top nodes

NAME                    CPU(cores)   CPU%   MEMORY(bytes)   MEMORY%   
mckakos-workers-qj5n0   653m         16%    2757Mi          41%       
mckakos-workers-qj5nd   869m         22%    2824Mi          42%
```

Answer (score 0):

After a few minutes of debug I notice the account is limit to 3 storageClass = "do-block-storage"

```
LAST SEEN   TYPE      REASON                    OBJECT                           MESSAGE
7m53s       Normal    NodeHasSufficientMemory   node/mckakos-workers-qr2lh       Node mckakos-workers-qr2lh status is now: NodeHasSufficientMemory
7m52s       Normal    Synced                    node/mckakos-workers-qr2lh       Node synced successfully
7m48s       Normal    RegisteredNode            node/mckakos-workers-qr2lh       Node mckakos-workers-qr2lh event: Registered Node mckakos-workers-qr2lh in Controller
7m43s       Normal    Starting                  node/mckakos-workers-qr2lh       
7m53s       Normal    Starting                  node/mckakos-workers-qr2lk       Starting kubelet.
7m53s       Warning   InvalidDiskCapacity       node/mckakos-workers-qr2lk       invalid capacity 0 on image filesystem
7m53s       Normal    NodeHasSufficientMemory   node/mckakos-workers-qr2lk       Node mckakos-workers-qr2lk status is now: NodeHasSufficientMemory
7m53s       Normal    NodeHasNoDiskPressure     node/mckakos-workers-qr2lk       Node mckakos-workers-qr2lk status is now: NodeHasNoDiskPressure
7m53s       Normal    NodeHasSufficientPID      node/mckakos-workers-qr2lk       Node mckakos-workers-qr2lk status is now: NodeHasSufficientPID
7m53s       Normal    NodeAllocatableEnforced   node/mckakos-workers-qr2lk       Updated Node Allocatable limit across pods
7m53s       Normal    RegisteredNode            node/mckakos-workers-qr2lk       Node mckakos-workers-qr2lk event: Registered Node mckakos-workers-qr2lk in Controller
7m52s       Normal    Synced                    node/mckakos-workers-qr2lk       Node synced successfully
7m41s       Normal    Starting                  node/mckakos-workers-qr2lk       
7m12s       Normal    NodeReady                 node/mckakos-workers-qr2lk       Node mckakos-workers-qr2lk status is now: NodeReady
2m53s       Warning   FailedScheduling          pod/mongodb1-b9ff8d947-6bkzr     0/2 nodes are available: 2 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims. preemption: 0/2 nodes are available: 2 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling.
2m51s       Normal    Scheduled                 pod/mongodb1-b9ff8d947-6bkzr     Successfully assigned default/mongodb1-b9ff8d947-6bkzr to mckakos-workers-qr2lh
2m48s       Normal    SuccessfulAttachVolume    pod/mongodb1-b9ff8d947-6bkzr     AttachVolume.Attach succeeded for volume "pvc-4580ea0a-032b-4709-b23b-cb7949116f01"
2m46s       Normal    Pulling                   pod/mongodb1-b9ff8d947-6bkzr     Pulling image "docker.io/bitnami/mongodb:6.0.4-debian-11-r10"
2m30s       Normal    Pulled                    pod/mongodb1-b9ff8d947-6bkzr     Successfully pulled image "docker.io/bitnami/mongodb:6.0.4-debian-11-r10" in 15.289609928s
2m29s       Normal    Created                   pod/mongodb1-b9ff8d947-6bkzr     Created container mongodb
2m29s       Normal    Started                   pod/mongodb1-b9ff8d947-6bkzr     Started container mongodb
2m54s       Normal    SuccessfulCreate          replicaset/mongodb1-b9ff8d947    Created pod: mongodb1-b9ff8d947-6bkzr
2m54s       Normal    ExternalProvisioning      persistentvolumeclaim/mongodb1   waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "dobs.csi.digitalocean.com" or manually created by system administrator
2m54s       Normal    Provisioning              persistentvolumeclaim/mongodb1   External provisioner is provisioning volume for claim "default/mongodb1"
2m54s       Normal    ScalingReplicaSet         deployment/mongodb1              Scaled up replica set mongodb1-b9ff8d947 to 1
2m53s       Normal    ProvisioningSucceeded     persistentvolumeclaim/mongodb1   Successfully provisioned volume pvc-4580ea0a-032b-4709-b23b-cb7949116f01
115s        Warning   FailedScheduling          pod/mongodb2-776c7764bc-nq4sr    0/2 nodes are available: 2 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims. preemption: 0/2 nodes are available: 2 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling.
114s        Warning   FailedScheduling          pod/mongodb2-776c7764bc-nq4sr    0/2 nodes are available: 2 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims. preemption: 0/2 nodes are available: 2 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling.
112s        Normal    Scheduled                 pod/mongodb2-776c7764bc-nq4sr    Successfully assigned default/mongodb2-776c7764bc-nq4sr to mckakos-workers-qr2lh
110s        Normal    SuccessfulAttachVolume    pod/mongodb2-776c7764bc-nq4sr    AttachVolume.Attach succeeded for volume "pvc-aaed51f6-b3fd-4b4a-8491-94d58750cc53"
104s        Normal    Pulled                    pod/mongodb2-776c7764bc-nq4sr    Container image "docker.io/bitnami/mongodb:6.0.4-debian-11-r10" already present on machine
104s        Normal    Created                   pod/mongodb2-776c7764bc-nq4sr    Created container mongodb
104s        Normal    Started                   pod/mongodb2-776c7764bc-nq4sr    Started container mongodb
116s        Normal    SuccessfulCreate          replicaset/mongodb2-776c7764bc   Created pod: mongodb2-776c7764bc-nq4sr
117s        Normal    ExternalProvisioning      persistentvolumeclaim/mongodb2   waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "dobs.csi.digitalocean.com" or manually created by system administrator
117s        Normal    Provisioning              persistentvolumeclaim/mongodb2   External provisioner is provisioning volume for claim "default/mongodb2"
116s        Normal    ScalingReplicaSet         deployment/mongodb2              Scaled up replica set mongodb2-776c7764bc to 1
115s        Normal    ProvisioningSucceeded     persistentvolumeclaim/mongodb2   Successfully provisioned volume pvc-aaed51f6-b3fd-4b4a-8491-94d58750cc53
54s         Warning   FailedScheduling          pod/mongodb3-5fc455c575-stmv6    0/2 nodes are available: 2 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims. preemption: 0/2 nodes are available: 2 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling.
52s         Warning   FailedScheduling          pod/mongodb3-5fc455c575-stmv6    0/2 nodes are available: 2 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims. preemption: 0/2 nodes are available: 2 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling.
50s         Normal    Scheduled                 pod/mongodb3-5fc455c575-stmv6    Successfully assigned default/mongodb3-5fc455c575-stmv6 to mckakos-workers-qr2lh
48s         Normal    SuccessfulAttachVolume    pod/mongodb3-5fc455c575-stmv6    AttachVolume.Attach succeeded for volume "pvc-ca34539f-47b1-4c13-8d98-d3aed5a035aa"
43s         Normal    Pulled                    pod/mongodb3-5fc455c575-stmv6    Container image "docker.io/bitnami/mongodb:6.0.4-debian-11-r10" already present on machine
43s         Normal    Created                   pod/mongodb3-5fc455c575-stmv6    Created container mongodb
42s         Normal    Started                   pod/mongodb3-5fc455c575-stmv6    Started container mongodb
55s         Normal    SuccessfulCreate          replicaset/mongodb3-5fc455c575   Created pod: mongodb3-5fc455c575-stmv6
55s         Normal    ExternalProvisioning      persistentvolumeclaim/mongodb3   waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "dobs.csi.digitalocean.com" or manually created by system administrator
55s         Normal    Provisioning              persistentvolumeclaim/mongodb3   External provisioner is provisioning volume for claim "default/mongodb3"
55s         Normal    ScalingReplicaSet         deployment/mongodb3              Scaled up replica set mongodb3-5fc455c575 to 1
53s         Normal    ProvisioningSucceeded     persistentvolumeclaim/mongodb3   Successfully provisioned volume pvc-ca34539f-47b1-4c13-8d98-d3aed5a035aa
2s          Warning   FailedScheduling          pod/mongodb4-857f9c8899-77gtx    0/2 nodes are available: 2 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims. preemption: 0/2 nodes are available: 2 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling.
3s          Normal    SuccessfulCreate          replicaset/mongodb4-857f9c8899   Created pod: mongodb4-857f9c8899-77gtx
3s          Normal    ExternalProvisioning      persistentvolumeclaim/mongodb4   waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "dobs.csi.digitalocean.com" or manually created by system administrator
2s          Normal    Provisioning              persistentvolumeclaim/mongodb4   External provisioner is provisioning volume for claim "default/mongodb4"
3s          Normal    ScalingReplicaSet         deployment/mongodb4              Scaled up replica set mongodb4-857f9c8899 to 1
1s          Warning   ProvisioningFailed        persistentvolumeclaim/mongodb4   failed to provision volume with StorageClass "do-block-storage": rpc error: code = ResourceExhausted desc = volume limit (3) has been reached. Current number of volumes: 3. Please contact support.
```

Comment: Eloberate more about question